# Map internal Wi-Fi strength?

Tags: wi-fi, gps, maps

I'm a system administrator for a school division, and we are upgrading our Wi-Fi network.  Is there a way that I can map the strength of the Wi-Fi signal at different places inside a building (where GPS does not work)?

I have used some stumblers -- Wi-Fi Analyzer and Meraki Wi-Fi Stumbler -- and those really do most of what I need, but I'd really like to see things on a map.  I've tried some standard wardriving applications -- such as WiGLE Wi-Fi Wardriving and Wi-Fi Map Maker - Free -- and they just don't really work without a GPS coordinate.

I'd be more than happy to snap a photo of a building map and indicate where I am at different places and be able to see, say, a heat-map of the signal strength (and better still if I could see if by BSSID).  I'd also be find with using the phone as a collection device and analyzing the data later on the computer.

Is there a way to map the Wi-Fi signal strength at different places in the buildings I'm providing Wi-Fi service to?

Comment: Thia question does not belong here.

Comment: @sam, is there a place you feel that it does belong, then?

Comment: Its a n/w related question and does not involve any android platform. You should ask this question on n/w forums.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [WiFi Mapper](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.osiris_mobile.wifimapper)?

Answer (score 2):

You could try "[WiFi Maps Light](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.renjuplay.tools.wifimapslight)" for Android, available for free in Google Play.

Comment: Recommending your own app is fine on this site (when it's relevant), but please abide by the rules and make it clear in your answer that it's your app.